# What happens when you sample from a discrete probability mass function according to its own pmf?

Tags: probability

I have a probability mass function (pmf) for a discrete distribution represented as a vector $x$ containing the full list of probabilities.  If I sample probabilities from $x$ according to this pmf with replacement,   what can we say about the resulting distribution of probabilities?  As mentioned in the comments, it won't be a pmf.

---

To make the question a little more concrete, say the original pmf is a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) or some other well known pmf with an easy closed form.

Comment: Can you give an example?  Suppose your vector (or transpose) was $(0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2)$.  Might a sample of size four look like $2,1,2,4$ or like $0.5,0.2,0.5,0.2$ ?  What would a "resulting distribution" look like?

Comment: @Henry Sorry  I was unclear. It would look like $0.5, 0.2,0.5,0.2$.

Comment: @Lembik it is not necessarily a pmf, since the probabilities  can add up to a number greater than one (as in your example). May I ask what the context of the question is?

Comment: @msm The original motivation comes from physics where people want to sample from some discrete space according to a computable pmf.  In order to verify how well one has sampled ideally one would understand the distribution of probabilities you get as  I describe in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking to understand the distribution of $p(X)$ where $X$ is a discrete random variable with pmf $p$. When all the $p_i$ are different, the situation is simple:

$$P(p(X)=p_i)=P(X=x_i)=p_i.$$

When $p_i$ can be duplicated, you have to take that into account, so that you have

$$P(p(X)=p_i)=P(X \in \{ x_j : p_j=p_i \})=p_i \cdot \# \{ j : p_j=p_i \}$$

where $\#$ denotes the number of elements in a finite set.

So in the example from the comments on the question,

$$P(p(X)=0.2)=0.4 \\ 
P(p(X)=0.5)=0.5 \\
P(p(X)=0.1)=0.1.$$

By contrast to this relatively complicated situation for discrete variables, for a random variable $X$ with a continuous CDF $F$, $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. This is related to the "probability integral transformation": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform

Comment: Thank you but I was looking for a little more than this. Take the case of the geometric distribution for the original pmf. Is there a mathematical closed form for the distribution we get from this process?

Comment: @Lembik Well, you can write down $P(p(X)=a(1-a)^{n-1})=a(1-a)^{n-1}$ for each $n=1,2,\dots$, and otherwise it is zero. Here $a$ is the success probability. (All of these probabilities are different, so you're in the "simple case".) What else would you want exactly?

Comment: You are right of course but.. there is some sort of transformation going on which I don't understand in general.  Maybe it would clarify if I drew curves for both the geometric distribution and its transformation.

Comment: @Lembik In the discrete case, there is no nice expression. In the continuous case, or more generally just the case when the CDF is continuous (regardless of it being differentiable), $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.

Comment: Aha! OK that is a crucial observation. Would you mind adding the answer for the continuous case (even though I didn't ask it) and I will accept it gladly.

Comment: @Lembik Done. ${}{}$